# In jquery use php variable to execute an enqueued jquery file

Tags: functions, jquery, wp-enqueue-script

I am loading some jquery on a specific Wordpress admin page, the jquery loads and works fine but I need have this jquery only trigger if a php variable exists.

In php I would just write a function and hook it into the admin page:

I am enqueuing the jquery file, i.e., foo.js that contains this following jquery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('#someID.some-class > a').append('<div class="caption"></div>');
    $(".caption").text("Add this text");
});
```

So the file foo.js file loads whenever the themes.php file is loaded but I do not want the jquery to run unless a variable is set by the themes.php page.

I am confused as to where and how I do check the variable and trigger the jquery.

Do I just add the jquery by echoing out the the jquery from within a function?

Do I somehow add the php variable check into the foo.js file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Do I just add the jquery by echoing out the the jquery from within a function?
>
> Do I somehow add the php variable check into the foo.js file?

No, off course no.

Use [wp_localize_script](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script). The original aim of this function was to translate the js scripts, but it allows to pass any kind of variables to js.

```
function register_foo() {
  wp_register_script('foo-js', plugins_url('js/foo.js', __FILE__), array('jquery'), null);
  $mydata = array(
    'foo' => 'bar', 'awesome' => 'yes'
  );
  wp_localize_script('foo-js', 'mydata', $mydata); // this one do the magic
  wp_enqueue_script('foo-js');
}
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'register_foo');
```

With this snippet the file 'foo.js' is inserted in admin pages, and a variable, that is a json object, is passed to the script and you can use it as you want.

Now, as example, in your 'foo.js' you can have;

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    var foo = mydata.foo;
    var awesome = mydata.awesome;
    if ( foo == 'bar' ) {
      $('#someID.some-class > a').append('<div class="caption"></div>');
      $(".caption").text("Is this script awesome? " + awesome + '!');
    }
});
```

Comment: that is just the solution I was looking for thanks.

Comment: thanks again, that worked perfectly and was the best solution anyone offered.

Comment: You are welcome. This is the only 'official' solution. There are some tricks, but...

Comment: Great, was looking for the same exact thing +1